# What causes ln: //: Is a directory?

Tags: bash, directory, symlink, autocomplete, slash

When linking a directory to root, I get this error:

```
$ ln -s ~/inbox/ /
$ ln: //: Is a directory
```

Bash autocompletes the directory path by adding a /. I've tried escaping without success.

```
$ ln -s ~/inbox /
```

works though.  Why is this?

Comment: What you wrote cannot work, I think you have to add more detail to your question. Also, are you working as root? Also, what exact OS are you on?

Comment: What OS is this?  Is it GNU Coreutils, or the BSD utils?

Comment: I don't think it's coreutils.  My version puts the file name in quotes, e.g. `ln: 'foo': hard link not allowed for directory`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [pathname resolution](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11), having a trailing `/` is equivalent to a trailing `/.` — in other words, `~/inbox/` is equivalent to `~/inbox/.` in this context. So the `ln` command is trying to create a link called `.` in the root directory (and, unsurprisingly, failing).

Zsh removes the trailing `/` when you press <kbd>Space</kbd> after completing a directory (unless configured not to do so). I don't know if bash can be made to do this.

Comment: Very interesting.  `Pathname resolution` also says that symlinks should be resolved.  But when you do `ln symlink blah`, `blah` should point to `symlink`, not what `symlink` points at.

Answer (score 0):

Is that exactly what you ran?

`Is a directory` looks like your OS printing the `EISDIR` error, which could happen two ways:

Trying to overwrite an existing symlink that points to a directory.

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ mkdir dir
$ ln -s dir dir    # this creates dir/dir
$ ln -s dir dir    # this fails, because dir/dir already exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link `dir/dir': File exists
```

Trying to create a hard link to a directory.

```
$ cd $(mktemp -d)
$ mkdir dir
$ ln dir dirlink
ln: `dir': hard link not allowed for directory
```

If it is what you were running, what does `type ln` or `alias ln` print?

Comment: I think it is good to explain what `cd $(mktemp -d)` does. Not everybody is familiar with this construction.

Comment: It creates a new directory somewhere under `/tmp`.  It makes sure that the files I'm using in my examples don't already exist so that everyone can get try running the commands and get the same results.